# Why does Kivy Plyer Storagepath not Save file to Android home and app Directory?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

I made a two simple Apps with Kivy that saves a Sqlite3 db file with the one App and json file with the other App to the `plyer.storagepath` built in directories.  The purpose was firstly, to test what is acceptable to the android environment and secondly to experience the simplicity as well as genius of the plyer project.

The problem is the `plyer.storagepath` does not want to save the files to the `storagepath.get_home_dir()`, `storagepath.get_root_dir()` and `storagepath.get_application_dir()` directories in the android environment.  I understand why the files will not be saved to the root directory, but why not the home and app directory?

#### Tried

1] Gave Storage permissions to Apps.

2] Used python's `os.path` library to get the App directory with `__file__` parameter and Home directory with `../../..` parameter.  This actually worked, but I still want to know why the `plyer.storagepath` made the Apps crash when I try to save to the home and application directories?

#### Sqlite3 file create code with python os.path

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import os
from os.path import dirname
import sqlite3 as sl
import datetime
import threading, time
import plyer

Builder.load_string('''
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<theData>:
    color: (0,0,0,1)
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (0.72,0,0,1)
    on_release: app.root.test_file(self)
<ActionButton>:
    background_normal: ''
<DataLabel>:
    size_hint_x: 0.5
    color: (0,0,0,1)
    text: ''
    on_release: app.root.get_ins(self)
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (0, 0.89, 0.32, 1)
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
<Data_Viewer>:
    id: mod_view
    size_hint: (0.8, 0.9)
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
    background: 'white.png'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: None
        size: mod_view.width, mod_view.height
        GridLayout:
            id: the_dat
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            space: 5
            padding: [0,7,0,7]

<ActionBar>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.14,0.5,0.71,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<TestAn>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: ''
                with_previous: False
                app_icon: ''
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Test'
                color: (0,0,0.56,1)
            ActionButton:
                id: view_gps
                Image:
                    source: 'i_5478.png'
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    size: self.parent.width /1.7, self.parent.height/ 1.7
                    allow_stretch: True
    Button:
        id: one_but
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9, 'right': 1}
        size_hint: [1,0.2]
        text: 'Hello User. Do you want to create a db file?'
        on_release: app.root.sow_dir()
    GridLayout:
        id: view_data
        cols: 1
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: Window.height / 4
        spacing: 2
        pos_hint: {'right': 1,'top': 0.7}


''')
class DataLabel(Button):
    pass
class theData(Button):
    pass
class Data_Viewer(ModalView):
    pass
class TestAn(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.view_data.add_widget(theData(text= str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
        self.ids.view_data.add_widget(theData(text= str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ ,"../..")))))
        self.ids.view_data.add_widget(theData(text= str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ ,"../../..")))))
        self.ids.view_data.add_widget(theData(text= str(plyer.storagepath.get_home_dir())))
        self.ids.view_data.add_widget(theData(text= str(plyer.storagepath.get_application_dir())))
        self.ids.view_data.add_widget(theData(text= str(plyer.storagepath.get_root_dir())))
    def sow_dir(self):
        m = Data_Viewer()
        m.ids.the_dat.clear_widgets()
        ff = App._get_user_data_dir
        if os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(__file__)):
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text=str(os.path.basename(__file__))))
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text=str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text=str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ ,"../..")))))
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text=str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ ,"../../..")))))
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text= str(plyer.storagepath.get_home_dir())))
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text= str(plyer.storagepath.get_application_dir())))
            m.ids.the_dat.add_widget(DataLabel(text= str(plyer.storagepath.get_root_dir())))
        m.open()
    def get_ins(self, instance):
        the_db = my_db()
        conn = the_db.create_db(instance.text)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        the_db.create_log_table(cur)
        the_db.log_data_entry(conn,cur, instance.text)
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
    def test_file(self, instance):
        the_path = (instance.text + '/test_entry.db')

        if os.path.isfile(the_path):
            ntitle = 'File Existence'
            nmessage = 'File Exists!'
            the_app_name = str(App.get_running_app().name)
            plyer.notification.notify(title=ntitle, message=nmessage,app_name=the_app_name,timeout=4,ticker='New Incoming Notification',toast=True)

class my_db():
    sql_err = (sl.IntegrityError, sl.OperationalError, sl.ProgrammingError, sl.InterfaceError)
    def create_db(self, db_dir):
        the_path = (db_dir + '/test_entry.db')
        conn = sl.connect(the_path)
        return conn
    def create_log_table(self, cur):
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_logs(\
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,\
                    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,\
                    test_file BLOB NOT NULL, \
                    date_created TEXT NOT NULL)')
    def log_data_entry(self,conn, cur, ins):
        ur = 1
        dte_created = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO test_logs(user_id, test_file, date_created)\
                        VALUES(?,?, ?)", (ur, ins, dte_created))
            conn.commit()
        except self.sql_err as err:
            cur.close()
class TheAnTestApp(App):
    title = 'The test App'
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'find_folderpath.png'
        return TestAn()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheAnTestApp().run()
```

#### Json file create code

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
import plyer
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.utils import platform

import datetime, json, os

Builder.load_string('''
#: import storagepath plyer.storagepath
<ThePlyThing>:
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 0.9}
        size_hint: [0.8, 0.05]
        text: 'Get Bluetooth status'
        on_release:
            root.get_info()
    Label:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.95, 'right': 0.9}
        size_hint: [0.8, 0.04]
        text: str(root.text)
    Label:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.91, 'right': 0.9}
        size_hint: [0.8, 0.04]
        text: str(root.info)
    TextInput:
        id: tit_notify
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.87, 'x': 0.05}
        size_hint: [0.9, 0.05]
        hint_text: 'Title'
    TextInput:
        id: mess_notify
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.82, 'x': 0.05}
        size_hint: [0.9, 0.05]
        hint_text: 'Message'
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.77, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.08]
        text: 'Get notified true..?'
        on_release: root.get_notified()
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.67, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Home'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_home_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.63, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'External Storage'
        on_press:
            label.text = str(storagepath.get_external_storage_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.59, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Root'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_root_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.55, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Documents'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_documents_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.51, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Downloads'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_downloads_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.47, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Videos'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_videos_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.43, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Music'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_music_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.39, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Pictures'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_pictures_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.35, 'x': 0.3}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.04]
        text: 'Applications'
        on_press: label.text = str(storagepath.get_application_dir())
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.67, 'x': 0}
        size_hint: [0.3, 0.04]
        text: 'New File'
        on_press: root.create_file()
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.67, 'x': 0.7}
        size_hint: [0.3, 0.04]
        text: 'Existence'
        on_press:
            root.test_file()
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.57,0.57,0.57,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        id: label
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.31, 'x': 0}
        size_hint: [1, 0.1]
    Button:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.20, 'x': 0.05}
        size_hint: [0.4, 0.05]
        text: 'Vibrate'
        on_press: root.get_vibe()
''')
class ThePlyThing(FloatLayout):
    info = ObjectProperty()
    text = StringProperty()
    dte = StringProperty()
    fil = StringProperty()
    text = "Bluetooth: "
    def get_notified(self):
        if self.ids.tit_notify.text != '' and self.ids.mess_notify.text != '':
            ntitle = str(self.ids.tit_notify.text)
            nmessage = str(self.ids.mess_notify.text)
            the_app_name = str(App.get_running_app().name)
            plyer.notification.notify(title=ntitle, message=nmessage,app_name=the_app_name,timeout=4,ticker='New Incoming Notification',toast=True)
    def get_info(self):
        if platform == 'android' or platform == 'ios': 
            self.info = str(plyer.bluetooth.info)
        else:
            self.info = 'Not supported'
    def get_vibe(self):
        if platform == 'android' or platform == 'ios':
            if plyer.vibrator.exists():
                plyer.vibrator.vibrate(4)
            else:
                the_app_name = str(App.get_running_app().name)
                plyer.notification.notify(title='No Vibrator', message='No Vibrator',app_name=the_app_name,timeout=4,ticker='New Incoming Notification',toast=True)
    def create_file(self):
        self.fil = self.ids.label.text
        if self.fil != "":
            self.dte = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
            dat = {}
            dat['newfile'] = []  
            dat['newfile'].append({  
                'name': 'File Exists!',
                'thedate': self.dte,
                'from': 'Herman'
            })

            with open(self.fil + '/data_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
                json.dump(dat, outfile)
    def test_file(self):
        self.fil = self.ids.label.text
        if self.fil != "":
            self.fil = self.fil + '/data_file.txt'
            if os.path.isfile(self.fil):
                the_app_name = str(App.get_running_app().name)
                with open(self.fil) as json_file:
                    rd_dat = json.load(json_file)
                    for p in rd_dat['newfile']:
                        if p['name']:
                            mess = p['name']
                        if p['thedate']:
                            mess = mess + ' ' + p['thedate']
                if mess != "":
                    plyer.notification.notify(title='File Exists', message=mess,app_name=the_app_name,timeout=4,ticker='New Incoming Notification',toast=True)
class AndyApp(App):
    title = 'The Ply Test'
    def build (self):
        self.icon = 'test_all_limits.png'
        return ThePlyThing()
    def on_pause(self):
        return True

AndyApp().run()
```

#### Expected Result

I want to create a file in the home and application directories using plyer out of the box.

Currenly the directories returned for each plyer storagepath are:

`storagepath.get_home_dir()`:  `/data`

`storagepath.get_root_dir()`: `/system`

`storagepath.get_application_dir()`:  `/data/user/0`

Comment: Can you post what plyer actually returns for each of those directories?

Comment: @inclement: I updated the current returned directories.

Comment: Either plyer has a bug, or its definition of home and root directories is poorly conceived. None of these directories are useful or ones you'd expect to be able to write to.